# Name for this Set

Tags: set-theory, terminology, forcing

In *Set Theory p. 209 - Jech (2003)*, the Jech performs the following construction:

Let $ B \in \mathbf{BoolAlg} $. For $ \alpha \in \mathbf{Ord} $ and $ \lambda \in \mathbf{Lim} $, let

- $ V_0 = \emptyset $,
- $ V_{\alpha^+} = \left\{ x : \operatorname{dom} x \to B \mid \operatorname{dom} x \subseteq V_\alpha \right\} $,
- $ V_\lambda = \bigcup_{\kappa < \lambda} V_\kappa $,

and let $ V = \bigcup_\alpha V_\alpha $.

Is there any name for this $ V $ - perhaps in particular with $ B = 2 $? Any answers appreciated! :)

Comment: Surely Jech does not use the $\alpha^+$ to denote the *ordinal* successor. The notation is used to denote *cardinal successor* in the context of set theory.

Comment: He does not! I've never heard of `successor cardinal', in our Set Theory course we used $ \alpha^+ $ for successor ordinals is all.